# How do I fly the chopper with the keyboard?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2, keyboard

No matter how boldly and self-confident I hop into a helicopter in Battlefield: Bad Company 2, it takes only 5 seconds for me to lose control and crash the vehicle.

How do you control the choppers with just the mouse and the keyboard? I don't want to use a joystick or a pad.

Specifically, what is the typical keyboard layout? Do I need to use keys for both turning and yaw?

I also need to see it in action, so a video of the screen and ideally the keyboards would be extra nice.

Comment: Do like I do: Jump in a chopper and quickly change position to take a gunner position. Then wait for an elite pilot to step in ;)

Comment: That is what I do at the moment, and people mostly thank me for it :)

Comment: Sorry but it's just a skill that takes practice to master. Keep at it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues starting out playing all Battlefield games. Flight in Helio type vehicles have been mostly unchanged on PC. The best way I've been able to control a helicopter (not using a joystick) is by using the Keyboard only. Using the mouse can be very tough, and sensitive.

Put both hands on the keyboard, left hand at WASD and right on the arrow keys. One hand will control propeller speed and yaw I believe. While the other hand will turn and tilt the chopper.

With some practice it should become a lot easier! This was all made with no modifications to key bindings.

Comment: will try that. Also need to set a key for primary fire, I guess.

Comment: works nicely. I can fly about 10 seconds now before I crash :)