# How do I control a Helicopter?

Tags: battlefield-play4free

I want to know if some of you know how to train controlling an helicopter. I love Battlefield P4F, but I still can't control a helicopter. Is there any free simulator (don't say FlightGear please) so that I can train, or is there any tutorials teaching the techniques?

Also, I can't use a joystick.

Comment: So you're asking us to recommend to you free helicopter simulation software that doesn't use a joystick? That's pretty much off-topic as it's a recommendation question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fly the chopper with the keyboard?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15384/how-do-i-fly-the-chopper-with-the-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I don't pilot planes and helicopters in games, but I can recommend to you Microsoft Flight Simulator — purely on the basis that there are tons of tutorials and guides for helicopters and planes, which you can follow to help improve your flying skills in a very accurate physics simulator. In addition to this, there are tons of websites that can help you with your flying skills even more, e.g. [hovercontrol.com](http://www.hovercontrol.com/).

Comment: PS you don't need a joystick for flight simulator.

Answer (score 5):

From someone who has spent [several hundred hours](http://bf2s.com/player/45991568/) in helicopters in BF2, the best way to do it is to practice. Practice makes perfect. Tips

1. For heli flying in the BF series, use keyboard+mouse combo. Joystick simply doesn't compare.
2. Start practicing with low sensitivity, pitch and yaw settings - it will be easier for you stabilize the heli. Ramp up all the settings as you get comfortable, as this will give you better maneuverability and quicker response.
3. Situtational awareness is very important. Know where your enemies and friends are. Constantly swap to external cameras. Always be aware of where to run to when you get in trouble.
4. Once you get good, use the map to your advantage. Fly low and use buildings and hills for cover.
5. Practice.
6. Practice.